# How to test that a specific sorting algorithm was actually implemented?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

I'm looking for an automated test to validate that merge sort was actually implemented. I know how to validate that a sorting algorithm actually sorts, but how do I validate that merge sort was used instead of, say, bubble sort?

I looked back at my old lectures and they hardcoded a target time of 0.01s for a 20,000 element list. They did not leave any comment of how they came up with 0.01s. So my question is how do I validate that merge sort was implemented?

The following code shows this "ghost" 0.01 that the lecture came up with. Where the did this 0.01 come from?

FYI, BIG_SORT_SIZE = 20,000

```
 /** @return true if test passes, else false */
 private boolean testTimeToSortBigList() {
    final int bigNum = BIG_SORT_SIZE; //okay, not THAT big
    final double maxTime = 0.02;
    final double targetTime = 0.01;
    try {
        IndexedUnsortedList<Integer> list1 = newList();
        Random rand = new Random(123);
        for (int i = 0; i < bigNum; i++) {
            list1.add(new Integer(rand.nextInt()));
        }

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Sort.sort(list1);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        double seconds = (double)totalTime/10e9;
        System.out.printf("\nTime to sort %d random integers: %.3f seconds\n", bigNum, seconds);
        System.out.printf("Target time < %.3f seconds. Time > %.3f suggests O(n^2) runtime.\n", targetTime, maxTime);

        return (seconds < maxTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("caught unexpected %s\n", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Time complexity has to do with input size `n`. If you pick a large enough `n`, then the difference between a linearithmic algorithm and a quadratic algorithm will be super obvious. So time your reference merge sort implementation on a large `n`, say, `n = 1_000_000` (it should be no more than a couple seconds), then run the reference bubble sort version (it should not complete in 30 seconds or longer). If the difference isn't obvious, increase `n` to `1_000_000_000`. At this point, the test is pretty simple. In other words, the value of `BIG_SORT_SIZE` is kinda critical.

Comment: So are you saying they used a sort function that they know actually implemented merge sort, and ran it using BIG_SORT_SIZE, got a 0.01 time and that's how they know to compare 0.01 to my implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but yeah, if it's less than 0.01 for whatever `BIG_SORT_SIZE` is on a particular machine, there's the cutoff. I wouldn't do it exactly like that, though, because based on the comments, `BIG_SORT_SIZE` is not that big. The trick is to choose a much larger number and run the solution in a thread or a subprocess that can be killed, or have a timeout on the test case. Just about every autograder works like that, or the test would run forever.

Comment: If bubble sort takes 0.02 and merge takes 0.01, that's too arbitrary and narrow a range and you can wind up with false positives and negatives. We need merge sort <= 1 second, bubble >= 30 seconds, and we'll set the test case timeout to 1 second, maybe 2 to allow some grace. In any case, there's no way to guarantee the student has implemented merge sort--they might have implemented quicksort or called `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: If you want to absolutely guarantee the student has implemented merge sort, then you'll need to have them return each sub-step of the sorting procedure and assert on each one.

Comment: Also, keep in mind random numbers can sometimes wind up being very optimal for certain sorts. If the array is in mostly sorted order, insertion sort runs in linear time rather than quadratic, for example. Kind of an edge case that you probably don't need to worry about, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @ggorlen BIG_SORT_SIZE = 20,000 in the code

Comment: "If bubble sort takes 0.02" @ggorlen how can you say this? Like do you know bubble sort takes 0.02? Are you just giving an example? Like the person that wrote this test, ran the 20,000 element list through bubble sort and it took 0.02 so that's how they came up with 0.01

Comment: Thanks. That `n` seems too small. I'll add an answer if I have time, but all the info is basically in the comments here for now. Yes, the numbers are arbitrarily chosen by the author, based on their machine at the time. If the user has a super fast computer, bubble sort will take 0.00 seconds on a measly 20k elements. That's why using a big `n` is important--it takes the speed of the machine out of the picture somewhat. Is this test suite used repeatedly on a single machine to grade students, or are students running this on their own arbitrary computers?

Comment: I edited my post to say what BIG_SORT_SIZE equals.

Comment: Are you using JUnit? If so, I'd use an `@Timeout` annotation.

Comment: This isn't a how to test question. My question is just how to validate that merge sort was actually implemented. Don't worry about what libraries are being used or methods, etc.

Comment: Fine, but keep in mind: the way you're doing it does not appear to be a good one at all, so I'd try to be a bit more open-minded to alternatives. For starters, if the student's `Sort.sort(list1);` involves `for (;;) {}` then what stops your test suite from running forever? The reason this test is so fragile is because no timeouts were used, so it really is the fundamental solution to your problem. Bubble sort == timeout, merge sort == pass. Simple as that. Your current design is: bubble sort runs a tiny bit slower, merge sort runs a tiny bit faster one some random person's machine. Not good.

Comment: My old professor wrote this code. I have no control over this example. This example was used to validate the assignment.

Comment: @tgdavies can you elaborate. I don't understand how that ensures merge sort was implemented over another algorithm.

Comment: Given that merge sorts are usually done recursively, I guess that isn't a very practical way to test it, but in general if you have a sort which proceeds by a series of steps, you can give it a known list of numbers, apply one step, and see if the list has changed in the way you expect for that algorithm.

Comment: Another way is to mock some data structure. For a recursive merge sort you could pass the sort function a `List` factory, which your test would mock to return mocks, and you could check that the expected methods were called on them (I might not use actual Mockito mocks in this case, probably my own instrumented wrapper around `List`.

Comment: What if I implement mergesort with a very elaborate way to compare two integers, like turning them to string and then comparing each character from right to left, so that it is a super slow comparison. Did I not implement mergesort? Or what if I had implemented quicksort or heapsort? How will the timing of the function help? Unless you can perform the sort step by step, you cannot know if mergesort was used.

Comment: Timing won't work. Many good sorting algorithms have similar time expectancy. You will have to either examine every program or provide some kind of callback that must be called that will tell you.

Comment: What is `IndexedUnsortedList`? Maybe a custom list implementation checking what the sort algorithm actually does?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I validate that merge sort was implemented?

If you only have the `Sort.sort` method and no other method that can execute the sort algorithm step by step, then this is not generally possible.

> The following code shows this "ghost" 0.01 that the lecture came up with. Where the did this 0.01 come from?

From a mind that made lots of assumptions about the computer that the program is running on and about the function that is being tested. This is not reliable, because:

- I could be running the program with mergesort implemented, but on an old computer that runs 100 times slower than modern day computers
- I could be running the same program on a virtual machine that is low on memory and thus triggers memory swaps to/from disk, slowing down things considerably
- I could be running the program on the worlds largest supercomputer, but using bubblesort, giving running times for 20,000 values that beat mergesort running on the same inputs on a "normal" PC.
- The function could implement another sort algorithm that has a similar running time, like some version of quicksort, introsort, tournament sort, heapsort, treesort, ...
- The mergesort implementation could use an inefficient comparison function, or inefficient swap function, slowing down the running time, but still implementing mergesort correctly. Similarly, it could have additional overhead, like logging actions to disk. But this would not make it *not* mergesort.
- The function could itself call the native (highly optimised) sort function (which is something like timsort) and then optionally add some artificial waiting time so to align with the expected running time of the testing code.

Even if you only wanted to know whether the implementation uses a O(log) algorithm, the main issue still is that time complexity *cannot be measured* by merely executing the implementation! A O(log) algorithm may need more time to sort 20,000 elements than a O(²) algorithm. Time complexity only tells us something about asymptotic growth, not about how measured running times will compare for a *chosen* input size.

Comment: As an addendum, since this test method does not seem to verify that the result is actually sorted, one could implement `sort` as an empty method and have the fastest solution in the world.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, if you don't have the code, is to sort objects with a custom comparator. This gives you the exact sequence of comparisons made. Which is very telling about the exact implementation.

But be warned, slight implementation changes will make it look like a different sort algorithm. For example with a merge sort, switching the recursive calls changes most of the comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably try with worst case examples to test the time differences for various algorithms . For example bubble sort on a very long sequence of decreasing numbers will perform much slower than merge sort for the same sequence. It is not automated but if you want to check the algorithm , this might be a brute force approach to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).